# Can we send two json response to two different components for a single request from one of the component using Flask web framework python?

Tags: python, flask

Currently we are getting request from tibco layer in the form of json and we are processing the request and sending json response back to tibco layer. Now along with this functionality, we want to send one more json response to a different component like tibco with some other details.

Comment: As of now, our code structure is as below:



.Cgi file:

import WSGIServer
import from_my_application import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer (app).run()



from_my_application.py

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', method=['post'])
def some_function():
    data = request.get_json()
    processed_data = process_data_function(data)
    return jsonify (processed_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

Comment: Here we are only sending one response to tibco layer. How can we send one more response to some other layer similar as tibco? Is it possible?